# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning development and I understand that there is a simple mistake somewhere, but I have been frozen for several hours already.

my model

```
class MonthModel {
  String name;
  
  List day = [];
  List facture = [];

  MonthModel({this.name});
  MonthModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map)
  : name = map['payments'] ?? '';

  
}

my repository:
```

---

```
class RealtimeRepository{
  //const RealtimeRepository();

  

  Future<List<MonthModel>> getMonth() async {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("payments");
    var monthSnapshot = await databaseReference.once();
    List<MonthModel> month = [];
    print(month);
    monthSnapshot.value.entries.forEach((e) {
      print(e);
      MonthModel data = MonthModel.fromJson(e.value);
      month.add(data);
      
    });
    print(month.length);
    return month;
  }
```

my builder:

```
class BuildView1 extends StatelessWidget {
  var lists =  RealtimeRepository().getMonth();
  //print(lists);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(title: Text(lists[]);  <--------------PROBLEM
      },
      
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of List I get instance of 'Future<List>
Why?

Comment: Because lists is not a list but a Future<List> and it must complete before you can display it. Have a look at [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: And you are missing `index` inside the `[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) in order to display data after the `Future` has complete :

```dart
class BuildView1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<MonthModel>>(
        future: RealtimeRepository().getMonth(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Wait for snapshot to complete
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            final list = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text(list[index]));
              },
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```